# How to debug this error?

Tags: java, batch-file

I have this error which I have tried to solve for a long time but to no avail. I wanted to pass a java string to a batch file. But there's error.

```
btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent args)
        {
            String fileToPath = chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
            try
            {   
                //create new process
                String command = "cmd /c start /wait "+DetectDrive+"\\imageinfo.bat";

                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{command,"\""+fileToPath+"\""});

                //cause this process to stop until process p is terminated
                p.waitFor();
            } 
            catch (IOException | InterruptedException e1)
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

I wanted to pass the String fileToPath to a batch file for some other purposes. For example in my batch file: `echo %1` if it works. But I got errors which I have a big time solving it.

Here's my error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmd /c start /wait E:\\imageinfo.bat": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at Volatility$3.actionPerformed(Volatility.java:187)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 40 more
```

I have no idea how to solve it. Can anyone help me with it? I'm new to java but debugging has always been my weakness. Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: A google search will provide you with a plethora of answers regarding Java debugging.

Comment: @Qix yea, i tried. but then.. i don't seem to be able to make it work

Comment: Does it work if you hard code the string instead? Does that command work from the command prompt? Can you run other commands that "obviously" work (`dir`,`echo HELLO`, etc.)? I would start there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are combining tokens into one String (`command`) but still passing a `String[]` to `exec`. This confuses exec

```
String[] command = 
    new String[]{"cmd", "/c", "start", "/wait",
                 DetectDrive+"\\imageinfo.bat", fileToPath}; 
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec( command );
```

Leave quoting of the fileToPath to exec.

**Later**

You can execute the subprocess in a separate Thread to avoid blocking your application.

Comment: For debugging such calls: Use ProcessBuilder, start and Process.waitFor, which returns an exit code of the subprocess. Although interpreting this is peculiar (OS dependent) it will usually provide a hint.

Comment: @1337 OK, but generally: beware of space in path names (Windows) and of multiple spaces anywhere in the original string, which will give you one or more spurious empty string arguments.

Comment: @laune hi laune, your solution works. but is it possible if I ask.. how can I make my cmd go background? so it's like.. when I clicked on the button "Start", instead of waiting for a cmd to pop out, is it possible to not make the cmd pop out???

Comment: Added a hint in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`Runtime.exec(String)` will run the whole string as one command. You should use
`Runtime.exec(String[])` with the first string in the array being the command and the others the parameters for the command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ProcessBuilder for passing parameter to a external process which is very easy.Following is the example for ProcessBuilder:

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\PathToExe\\MyExe.exe","param1","param2").start();
```

Where param1 and Param2 are parameters.You can pass as many parameter as you want.
Hope these answer your question.